# Why doesnt my php script work

Tags: php, apache, twisted

All I want to do (initially) is the following:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

I have two different web servers running.  If I try to open the above in firefox, Under any filename, with the :80 port from apache, it merely echoes the above.

If I try to open the above, as any filename, from a python twisted web server on port :8888, I get a http 500 error (CGI Script Error

Premature end of script headers.)!

I am running Gentoo linux.  I have installed and re-installed cgi different ways.  Anything other file, not using CGI,  is served up as expected with both web servers.

Comment: Do you have the required settings for PHP in your httpd.conf file?

Comment: This may be a serverfault.com question as the problem is that the webserver isn't serving PHP files properly.

Answer (score 1):

And the winner is:

```
<IfDefine PHP5>
    # Load the module first
    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
            LoadModule php5_module    modules/libphp5.so
            AddHandler php5-script php
            AddHandler php5-script html
            AddType text/html       php
    </IfModule>

    # Set it to handle the files
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p5?|tml)$">
            SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
            SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>

    DirectoryIndex index.php index.phtml
```

I don't really know what I am doing yet.  All I know is I achieved the desired effect:  any *.php or *.html file in my root htdocs directory will correctly render php SCRIPTS.  I found a lot of confusion in web posttings about what this entails.  My php scripts start with  `<?` and end with `?>`  It was not necessary to write `<?php`, nor is it necessary to write out any http headers in a *.php file.

Comment: But this is not CGI. This is mod_php.

Comment: True.  The CGI error was coming from the python twisted web server.  Sorry to confuse you all.  I just wanted to be able to render a php script within a *.php or *.html file.  It didn't work with apache, so I tried opening with the python twisted web server. 

Thanks for the help, Ignacio.

Answer (score 0):

you need not run the php as a cgi-bin. just put the file under htdocs folder.

make sure you loaded mod_php5 in the httpd.conf using LoadModule

and restart the server -> apachectl restart

it will work out of the box

Answer (score -1):

You need to output the headers for CGI first:

```
<?php
echo "Content-type: text/html\n";
echo "\n";

phpinfo();
?>
```

Refer to [the CGI documentation](http://hoohoo.ncsa.illinois.edu/cgi/) for more info.

**EDIT:**

Under httpd, you need to put the script in `cgi-bin/` and access it via there, e.g. `http://example.com/cgi-bin/phpinfo.php`.

Comment: just echoed the extra stuff (the two echoes), and exact same response from python.

Comment: That gets rid of the 500 error, sure enough.  But I guess I will have to go over to Gentoo.org and do some more research.  I can run only scripts in the cgi-bin.  How do I call phpinfo() from a script?